# In Tableau, is it possible to create a calculated field that sum values from one column for every unique value in 2 other fields

Tags: tableau-api

Here's a sample what my raw data would look like:

[image]

I'm looking to create a new field that sums up `revenue` for all owners regardless of whether or not they're the `owner` or `secondary_owner` for each account/day/other-field combination. Here's what this would look like if the sample data were aggregated by owner/dt:

[image]

Some notes:

- It's known/expected that the total revenue displayed for this calculated field will be double that of the revenue booked (given all accounts have 2 owners).
- `owner_name` cannot be `NULL`, but `secondary_owner_name` can be; it's OK to show a value for a `NULL` owner.

I could hack my way through this by manually building out some funky `CASE WHEN` sequence, but I feel like there *should* be a more elegant solution here

Comment: If you can use custom SQL, you could create a UNION join and stack the two owner fields.

Comment: Pivot the data.

Comment: @Bernardo - thanks! I think that's probably the best option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible until and unless the owner or secondary_owner are two different columns.

One trick that you can play here is:

- Within the excel file create two sheets "owner" and "secondary_owner"

  - **Owner** sheet will have columns account_name, date, owner and revenue.
  - **secondary_owner** sheet would have account_name, date, secondary_owner and revenue.
  - Now go to data source tab and refresh the data source you will see two options "owner" and "secondary_owner" for the selected source. Union both of these with the tableau union feature.
  - When you go back to your tableau sheets you will see a additional column which tableau adds "data_source".
  - Double click the owner dimension
  - Double click the revenue measure and you're done...!

I arrived at this solution given the values are expected/known to be double when data is organized this way.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - a couple responses. owner & secondary_owner are already two different columns in my source data. My source data is in redshift, but I think the UNION option presented here should also work (same as what @Bernardo mentioned in the question comment above)

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this using data blending

1. Duplicate your tableau data source, by right clicking on it and selecting duplicate
2. Use the Data menu to define a custom relationship between both owner name in the first data source to **secondary** owner name in the second data source, and also between the dt field in both data sources.
3. Select the first data source and drag owner name and dt to rows, and make sure dt is set to discrete MDY or exact date, making that data source primary (blue check mark). Place SUM(revenue)on columns if you like.
4. Select the second data. Place SUM(revenue) on columns also.
5. Select the primary data source. You can now create a calculated field that adds both measures. The secondary measure will need the data source name as a prefix before the field name in the calc. The easiest way to do that is to drag and drop the field from the data pane to the calc window

Read the docs on data blending for more info

Comment: Hmm - interesting. Can you confirm this is the tool/feature you're referencing? https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/multiple_connections.htm I plan to use the UNION method presented in the other answer (and question comment), but if I run into issues there, I'll check this out. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is the feature. Data blending. It means combining the results that are returned from two separate (aggregate/aka Group By) queries. Data blending can get a bit tricky in some cases, but in the right circumstances, it can be an efficient easy solution. This seems to be one of the happy cases for data blending